# MongoDB ISO TimeZone Issue In Pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

I am having a problem with timezone in ETL. While taking datefield from MongoDB (not as a JSON Document) using MongoDB input, the timezone difference is added to the date.When inserting this data to another database the added timezone difference is not applied there.Similar issue occurs in Mongodb output step

```
  Actual Date In MongoDB

 "date1" : ISODate("2015-01-31T18:30:00.000Z"),

 PDI Preview Of MongoDB Input 

 date1 :
 2015/02/01 00:00:00.000
```

Is there any provision to set a common timezone(or no timezone awarness) in Pentaho Data Integration, so that the same time from data source is inserted into the destination without any application of timezones.

Comment: were u able to solve this...??